# Animation for input text does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, css

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="First_Name" autofocus placeholder="First Name" onfocus="this.value = &#39;&#39;;">
<label id="Fname" style="color: red;"></label>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var firstname = document.getElementById('First_Name');
 var firstnamevalue = firstname.value.trim();
 if (firstnamevalue == '') {
      call=false;        
      shake(firstname);       
 }
 function shake (element){
      element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe8e6';
      element.classList.add('errorr');
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.classList.remove('errorr');
        }, 300);     
        e.preventDefault();
 }
```

CSS:

```
.errorr {
    position: relative;
    animation: shake1 .1s linear;
    -webkit-animation: shake1 .1s linear;
    -moz-animation: shake1 .1s linear;
    -o-animation: shake1 .1s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 4;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 4;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 4;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 4;
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% { 
        left: -5px; 
    }
    100% { 
        right: -5px; 
    }
};
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% { 
        right: 5px; 
    }
    0% { 
        left: 5px; 
    }
};
@-moz-keyframes shake {
    0% { 
        right: 5px; 
    }
    0% { 
        left: 5px; 
    }
};
@-o-keyframes shake {
    0% { 
        right: 5px; 
    }
    0% { 
        left: 5px; 
    }
};
```

I have checked this code of animation on opera, chrome and firefox.
Its working on chrome and opera but not in firefox .
I have firefox 45.0.1.
also i have tried with different versions of firefox , non of the version works.
please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: I put this code into a codepen and it did not work at all (Chrome) maybe make a codepen and post a link so we can see it working>

Comment: i also try it in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/57oj8tx6/   not working any where ....

Comment: still it doesnt work in firefox ..

Comment: issue hass been solved . i had small mistake in js which was not allowing to execute the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in keyframes.
In `@keyframes` (no-prefix) you have `0% {left: -5px;}`, `100% {right: -5px}`
In other (with-prefix) you have two keyframe, both with `0%`.

For some reason animation with `left` and `right` will not work in FF.

It's better use only one (`left` or `right`) property and animate it from `-5px` to `5px` or use `transform` property.

[Fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/24e94bsk/)

Comment: Thanx @Aleksandr Petrov